# Python unit testing a request that fails

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to test a http call that is supposed to fail but I want to return a value. However the test I do doesn't pass in the coverage :

```
    def callAPI(self, tokenURL:str):
    requestBuilder: RequestBuilder = RequestBuilder()

    try:
        response = requestBuilder.get(tokenURL)
        return response.json()
        # return "content"
    except Exception as err:
        Logger.error("An error occured while trying to call API "+ err)
        return None
```

This is my test function :

```
@responses.activate
def testCallDemFails():
  responses.add(
    responses.GET, 'http://calldem.com/api', json="{'err'}", status=500)

  with pytest.raises(Exception):
    demConfig = DemConfig()
    resp = demConfig.callAPI('http://callAPI.com/api/1/foobar')
    print("testCallAPIFail", resp)
    assert resp == None
```

The requestBuilder.get method just return a request.get function. When I execute the function, I don't even have the testAPI fail. Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the test function is not wiring up the request URL you are using to the response URL you are expecting. `http://callAPI.com/api/1/foobar` does not match `http://calldem.com/api`, nor is the test response configured as a regex match which would enable the sub-path matching that is implied by the example code. I am guessing that the response being returned by the misconfigured URL mapping is JSON parseable (or None), therefore the exception is never being raised.

If you try the following test code, does it work?:

```
import re

@responses.activate
def testCallDemFails():
  responses.add(
    responses.GET, re.compile('http://callAPI.com/api/.*'), json="{'err'}", status=500)

  with pytest.raises(Exception):
    demConfig = DemConfig()
    resp = demConfig.callAPI('http://callAPI.com/api/1/foobar')
    print("testCallAPIFail", resp)
    assert resp == None
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, i realized that the request.get doesn't raise an exception on error 500. The problem came from the error handling in the custom request class that I had